# Jump to html anchor using dash-bootstrap-component button in python

Tags: python, html, plotly-dash, dash-bootstrap-components

I'm trying to get a button to jump/scroll to a certain part of the webpage using dash-bootstrap-components. The anchor is added to the URL correctly, but the webpage doesn't move.

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

layout = html.Div([
...
  html.Div([
    dbc.Button('Record Information', id='record-info-btn', href='#record-info'
                className='btn btn-orange align-middle btn btn-secondary')])
...
  html.Div([
    dbc.Form([
      html.Div([
        dbc.FormGroup([
          html.Div([
            html.H3('Record Information', id='record-info')
            ...
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ])
], className='whitContainerHalf')
```

I've tried using dbc.NavLink instead of Button, but the same thing happens.

Answer (score 1):

According to the dbc documentation, Button has an href field that can link to an internal id or an external url; however, according to an [issue on their repo](https://github.com/facultyai/dash-bootstrap-components/issues/318#:%7E:text=Using%20a%20dbc.Button%20with%20an%20href%20to%20a,only%20after%20selecting%20refresh%20in%20the%20browser%20%28Chrome%29.), it doesn't work for internal ids. You have to use html.A() to jump to the section.

```
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

layout = html.Div([
...
  html.Div([
    html.A(dbc.Button('Record Information', id='record-info-btn', 
                      className='btn btn-orange align-middle btn btn-secondary'), 
           href='#record-info')
  ])
...
  html.Div([
    dbc.Form([
      html.Div([
        dbc.FormGroup([
          html.Div([
            html.H3('Record Information', id='record-info')
            ...
          ])
        ])
      ])
    ])
  ])
], className='whiteContainerHalf')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this offers a better demonstration:

```
app.layout = html.Div([

   html.Div([
    html.A(dbc.Button('Record Information', id='record-info-btn'), 
           href='#record-info')
  ]),

  html.Div([
      html.Div([], style={'display': "block", 'height': "2000px"}),
          html.Div([
            html.H3('Record Information', id='record-info')
          ])
  ])
])
```